# How to keep screen position while typing to input placed outside container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a problem with input/text-area element in absolute position being placed half way outside container. Screen position seems to follow the caret but I would really like to be able to keep writing and hide part of the text outside parent element. Is there any way to disable screen scrolling while typing outside the container? It would be perfect if the input text wouldn't scroll either, just hide whatever will be typed beyond parent and input field.

To explain it better I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1umr2ufz/)

```css
.wrapper {
 width : 200px;
 height: 150px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 border :1px solid #ccc;
}
input.test1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 5px;
 width: 250px;
 
}
input.test2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 90px;
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>

<input type="text" class="test1" />
<input type="text" class="test2" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('.wrapper').on('scroll', function() {
    $('.wrapper').scrollLeft(0);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
 width : 200px;
 height: 150px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 border :1px solid #ccc;
}
input.test1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 5px;
 width: 250px;
 
}
input.test2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 90px;
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>

<input type="text" class="test1" />
<input type="text" class="test2" />

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that resolves my wrapper scrolling. is there any known solution to stop text scrolling inside input field? Arg0n I've voted up your answer but due to my low reputation it doesn't seem to appear in public forum. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess you could set `maxlength` attribute on the inputs to prevent the scroll.

Comment: I have also used .scroll() method on input element but I will see what result I will get with maxlenght. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to fix the spacing on the input boxes? If so, all I did was add a space between the "input" and ".test1" and ".test2". This would fix the issue of having the first text box halfway off the div.

```css
.wrapper {
 width : 200px;
 height: 150px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 border :1px solid #ccc;
}
input .test1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 5px;
 width: 250px;
 
}
input .test2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 90px;
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>

<input type="text" class="test1" />
<input type="text" class="test2" />

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, the position of the input fields will be random therefore spacing between them doesn't matter to me. Actually it must be half way outside the parent. I am looking to disable scrolling inside the input if the test is longer then a field. Also screen/camera position ( as I have no better words to describe it) follows the caret while typing, I am looking the way to keep it in the original position even if the cursor is placed at the end of the test line.